# extract names from a delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string

```
 '/path/to/file/123'
```

I want to extract the following in sql

```
'file'
```

Comment: https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-split-a-string-in-oracle/ perhaps

Comment: The question is, actually, what exactly do you want to extract? Is it the 3rd "substring"? Or is it the penultimate substring? Or ...? Because, solution (although it seems you got what you wanted) depends on **rules** you forgot to specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('/path/to/file/123', '[^/]+', 1, 3)
  FROM dual;
```

Thank you